# How can I find an answer I posted to a question that contains an image?

Tags: support, search

I want to find an answer I posted to a question that contains an image. I just remember that the OP had attached an image to their question, and that I answered it. I need to see that again.

How can I find this post?

Comment: [Go here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2138752/c-link?tab=answers), open each in turn, look to see if its the one you're looking for.

Comment: OMG! I've to check all the answers?

Comment: Yeah. There is no search for "find all answers on questions with an image".  You might be able to search for your name and "imgur" on google, but that probably won't help much.  I could find it within ten minutes simply by opening your answers up en masse.

Comment: Thanks anyway I found what I wanted to see.

Comment: Related: [Add "hasImage:1" or "img:1" advanced search operators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a work-around, not a solution: search for `url:"*.png"`. The `url:` operator matches both regular hyperlinks and image links.

Combined with other operators this should help at least narrow down the number of candidates.

Other searches to try:

```
url:"i.*imgur.com"  # matches both i.imgur.com and i.stack.imgur.com images
url:"*.jpg"
url:"*.gif"
```

etc. Go creative!

There is, unfortunately, no way to restrict searching to 'questions I answered'. You could use a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for that instead, if you know some SQL. There already is a [query that searches questions you answered](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66819/questions-i-answered-containing-some-text) there.

Plugging in your Stack Overflow userid and the text `i.stack.imgur.com` gives me [82 results](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66819/questions-i-answered-containing-some-text?UserId=2138752&Text=i.stack.imgur.com). Perhaps that helps narrow it down a little.